# Trying to read CSV - I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python

I am relatively a very new person to python and I am trying to open a csv file.

I have placed my csv file in the location where I have my .py file and I am using the below code

```
import csv
with open ('anscombe.csv', 'r') as datafile:
    csv_reader =  csv.reader(datafile)
for line in csv_reader:
       print(line)
```

and getting this error

```
C:\Users\iyera\PycharmProjects\Anscombe\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/iyera/PycharmProjects/Anscombe/New import.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iyera\PycharmProjects\Anscombe\New import.py", line 5, in <module>
    for line in csv_reader:
**ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.**
```

Comment: You need to indent `for line...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PyCharm, you are just closing your file before use.
This should work

```py
with open ('anscombe.csv', 'r') as datafile: 
    csv_reader = csv.reader(datafile) 
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

`with` opens the file at the start of the block and closes it at the end by calling the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of file at start and end. For more information read: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Answer (score 1):

Seems issue with identation. When you came out of `with` statement the file is closed.

```py
import csv
with open ('anscombe.csv', 'r') as datafile:
    csv_reader =  csv.reader(datafile)
    for line in csv_reader:
       print(line)
```